# How to pass contant string value for a column in SUMMARIZECOLUMN

Tags: dax

I want to pass a constant string value i.e. Not Applicable for one of the column values that will be used in SUMMARIZECOLUMNS function. But I am not find any  format in how to do the same.

Comment: do you want to assign "Not Applicable" value in that column for all rows or based on condition with some other column value. Also can you share an example of what you are exactly looking for ?

Comment: Yes but there is no condition just that Not Applicable value should reflect in all rows for that particular column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS( table_name[column_name], "Custom_Column_Name", "Not Applicable")
```